# How to export npm library source code to be available for apps that use the library?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am creating my first react library, I can publish to npm and use it as a dependency but I can't access the library source on the app that uses the library.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-lib-my-test",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "testing npm library",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --display-modules",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-intl": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "react-code-blocks": "0.0.7",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const pkg = require('./package.json');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",

    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "index.js",
        library: pkg.name,
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [ "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react" ],
                        plugins: [ "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions", "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "react-hot-loader/babel" ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

and `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

In another app I can import the npm dependecy `react-lib-my-test` and the component is working, but I can't view the source code.
This is an image of the app using this dependency:
[image]

I can't open the `Test` component. I think it some configuration in the library, but I don't know what.

`Test` component code:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Test = ({testmsg}) => {

    const [msg, setMsg] = React.useState(testmsg);

    return(
        <>
            <div >
                TEST
                <div>{msg}</div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```